# Opening web page as I see it in browser with Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, urllib

Using the google CSE utilities I've made a HTML file that is a barebones version of Google Search (about 1/10th page size), which is as follows:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '011947631902407852034:gq02yx0e1mq';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

I can open this in my browser like C:\Users\Me\Documents\MyWebpage.html?q=MyQuery and it shows something like this:

[image] This is obviously not what's in the HTML file, so I assume it's generated via JavaScript. Indeed, when I look at the page in my browser there's a lot more HTML than is in the actual file. The 1/10th size comment refers to the size of all of this, if I download it using Inspect Element, selecting the topmost node, Edit HTML, and copying all the HTML and placing it in a file.

My question is: how can I read in all of this HTML for a given query with Python?

Comment: Check out the JS file you're loading and implement that code in python. Oh, and the other scripts that it is loading.

Comment: Opening the cse.google.com url by manually appending the cse variable gets me this file, which appears to be styling info: https://hastebin.com/uzoretulix.tex. I found [this](https://www.google.com/uds/api/search/1.0/30a7b43bf733edc52dc094738e892a6c/default+en.I.js) JS file in Inspect Element which I assume is the majority of it but I can't make heads or tails of it.

I really just need a way to get what I get in Inspect Element with a python script.

Comment: No, this ain't styling, this loads the main lib for cse. And as you see in that file, it consists of about 700 lines of dense JS, just to fetch the data from google and build the search results you are looking for.

Comment: I see. I'm still not really any closer to achieving what I want to, which is to somehow get Python to behave like a browser given this link/filepath and render out the JS to get the whole file path